# Azure SQL Access Token Error - The server is not currently configured to accept this token

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, access-token

I am using the following code to retrieve an access token so that my application can access an Azure SQL database:

```
        public static SqlConnection CreateAzureConnection(IConfiguration _configuration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var objDefaultAzureCredentialOptions = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                ExcludeEnvironmentCredential = false,
                ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true,
                ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true,
                ExcludeVisualStudioCredential = false,
                ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true,
                ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true,
                ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = true
            };

            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(objDefaultAzureCredentialOptions);

            var token = credential.GetToken(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" }), cancellationToken);

            SqlConnection conn = new(_configuration.GetConnectionString("Sales"))
            {
                AccessToken = token.Token
            };

            return conn;
        }
```

This seems fine and I get a token back but when I attempt to connect and run a query I get the following error:

*One or more errors occurred. (Login failed for user ''. The server is not currently configured to accept this token.)*

I have tried changing the options for what credentials to exclude. The app will be deployed onto an approved environment, but my local dev area is not approved so I have added the VS credentials option. I've confirmed that my credentials in Tools > Options > Azure Service Authentication are correct.

When I use only environment credentials it fails to get the token at all, so I believe everything about the token itself is fine. The error mentions the server not being configured for this token type, so i'm guessing there's some setup that's needed on the Azure SQL server itself, but i've been unable to find what so far

Comment: Hi, have you checked with your database administrator if the SQL server virtual server is set up to allow Azure AD authentication? 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell#provision-azure-ad-admin-sql-managed-instance

Comment: I believe everything is set up to use Azure AD, I can log into the database via SSMS using Azure AD at least

Answer (score 1):

I have created webapp in visual studio and connected to Azure SQL database using below process:
I have given connection string in appsetting.json file
as

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "QuotesDatabase": "Server=tcp:<servename>.database.windows.net,1433; Database=<databasename>;" }
```

Image for reference:

[image]

I added required packages to connect database.
Packages:

[image]

I used below code to connect Azure SQL database:

```
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("<connectionstringname>");
            services.AddTransient(a =>{
                var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
                var token = credential
                        .GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(
                            new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" }));
                sqlConnection.AccessToken = token.Token;
                return sqlConnection;
```

Image for reference:

[image]

I used below query to retrieve data from SQL database:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SqlMSI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class QuotesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly string connectionString;
        public QuotesController(SqlConnection dbconnection)
        {
            DbConnection = dbconnection;
        }

        public SqlConnection DbConnection { get; }
      
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            DbConnection.Open();
            var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from quote", DbConnection);
            var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            var quotes = new List<Quote>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var quote = new Quote()
                {
                    Id = Guid.Parse(reader["Id"].ToString()),
                    QuoteNumber = int.Parse(reader["QuoteNumber"].ToString())
                };
                quotes.Add(quote);
            }
            return Ok(quotes);
        }
    }
    public class Quote
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int QuoteNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Image for reference:

[image]

I set myself as azure service authentication to retrieve the token credentials.

Image for reference:

[image]

I set myself as admin to the SQL server in Azure portal.

Image for reference:

[image]

I added webapp IP address to the SQL server
Image for reference:

[image]

It run successfully and connected to azure SQL database and retrieve the data from database without any error.

Image for reference:

[image]

It worked in my machine please recheck from your end.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without setting it as admin to the entire server?